# Is there a way to find out how many numbers are at the end of a string without knowing the exact index?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a method that extracts a certain substring from a string. This substring consists of the numbers in the string. Then this is parsed to an integer.

Method:

```
protected int startIndex() throws Exception {
    String str = getWorkBook().getDefinedName("XYZ");
    String sStr = str.substring(10,13);

    return Integer.parseInt(sStr) - 1;
}
```

Example:

String :

> '0 DB'!$B$460

subString :

> 460

Well, I manually entered the index range for the substring. But I would like to automate it.

My approach:

```
String str = getWorkBook().getDefinedName("XYZ");
int length = str.length();
String sStr = str.substring(length - 3, length);
```

This works well for this example.

Now there is the problem that the numbers at the end of the string can also be 4 or 5 digits. If that is the case, I naturally get a `NullPointerException`.

Is there a way or another approach to find out how many numbers are at the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would recommend to use regex with replaceAll like this:

```
String sStr = str.replaceAll(".*?([0-9]+)$", "$1");
```

This will extract the all the digits in the end or your String or any length.

Also I think you are missing the case when there are no digit in your String, for that I would recommend to check your string before you convert it to an Integer.

```
String sStr = str.replaceAll(".*?([0-9]+)$", "$1");
if (!sStr.isEmpty()) {
    return Integer.parseInt(sStr) - 1;    
}
return 0; // or any default value
```

Comment: regex yes, but replaceAll may apply the regex multiple times on the search string (if there are multiple (blocks) of numbers present and in the end all numbers will be merged to one large number block.

Comment: @Robert honestly I don't get you, can you explain with an example please!

Comment: Look at the example input `'0 DB'!$B$460` in the question. Your code returns `0460` instead of `460`. In this case because the first number is a `0` the parsed number will be the same, but if there is a number(s) different to 0 your code fails.

Comment: @Robert correct, I missed to add the `$` in the regex `.*?([0-9]+)$`, fix it.

Comment: So this works fine. Thanks for this new approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex, `(?<=\D)\d+$` which means one or more digits (i.e. `\d+`) from the end of the string, [preceded by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) non-digits (i.e. `\D`).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getNumber("'0 DB'!$B$460"));
    }

    static String getNumber(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)\\d+$").matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group();
        }

        // If no match is found, return the string itself
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the last number, you can go through the entire string on revert and get the start index:

```
protected static int startIndex() {
    String str = getWorkBook().getDefinedName("XYZ");

    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(str.length() - 1))) {
        for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                return i+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and then print it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int start = startIndex();
    if(start != -1)
       System.out.println(getWorkBook().getDefinedName("XYZ").substring(start));
   else 
      System.out.println("No Number found");
}
```

You will have to add the

Answer (score 1):

Simple and fast solution without RegEx:

```
public class Main
{
    public static int getLastNumber(String str) {
        int index = str.length() - 1;
        while (index > 0 && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(index)))
            index--;
            
        return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index + 1));        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String text = "'0 DB'!$B$460";
        System.out.println(getLastNumber(text));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
460
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were going to do this I just search from the end.  This is quite efficient. It returns -1 if no positive number is found.  Other return options and the use of an `OptionalInt` could also be used.

```
String s = "'0 DB'!$B$460";
int i;
for (i = s.length(); i > 0 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i-1)); i--);
int vv = (i < s.length()) ? Integer.valueOf(s.substring(i)) : -1;
System.out.println(vv);
```

Prints

```
460
```

If you know that there will always be a number at the end you can forget the ternary (?:) above and just do the following:

```
int vv = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(i));
```