# Is there a way to find special subStrings in this case with regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a string from which numbers are extracted at the end of the String with regex.

String:

> '0 DB'!$B$460

subString:

> 460

I solve this as follows:

```
String str = "'0 DB'!$B$460";
String sStr = str.replaceAll(".*?([0-9]+)$", "$1");
```

Old question Link:
[Is there a way to find out how many numbers are at the end of a string without knowing the exact index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308815/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-many-numbers-are-at-the-end-of-a-string-without-k?noredirect=1#comment115459577_65308815)

Now I have a different kind of string from which I want to extract certain ranges.

String:

> '0 DB'!$U$305:$AH$376

Here I would extract certain areas to the left of colon and to the right of colon.

Once the area between the dollar signs($), and the number after it. The respective areas can have different lengths. The part before the first dollar sign can consist of letters as well as numbers

So that would be 4 substrings.

subStrings:

> 1: U
>
> 2: 305
>
> 3: AH
>
> 4: 376

I was thinking of solving this with regex as well. But unfortunately my knowledge in this regard is limited.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this with regex? Or are there other ways?

Thanks

Comment: You can use 4 capturing groups `^.*?([A-Z])\$(\d+):\$([A-Z]+)\$(\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/SHMmlM/1 Or the subparts for both strings `^.*?([A-Z])\$(\d+)(?::\$([A-Z]+)\$(\d+))?$` https://regex101.com/r/r5gVSC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you can simply use the regex, `(?<=\\$)\\w+` which means [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) word characters [preceded by](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `$`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "'0 DB'!$U$305:$AH$376";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$)\\w+").matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
U
305
AH
376
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a specific pattern to get the 4 parts as capturing groups.

```
^.*?([A-Z])\$(\d+):\$([A-Z]+)\$(\d+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline 0+ times in a non greedy way
- `([A-Z])\$` Capture a char A-Z in group 1 and match `$`
- `(\d+):\$` Capture 1+ digits group 2 and match `:$`
- `([A-Z]+)\$` Capture 1+ chars A-Z in group 1 and match `$`
- `(\d+)` Match 1+ digits in group 4
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHMmlM/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wndGWf)

Example code

```
String regex = "^.*?([A-Z])\\$(\\d+):\\$([A-Z]+)\\$(\\d+)$";
String string = "'0 DB'!$U$305:$AH$376";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

---

To also match both example string, you can make the second part optional.

```
^.*?([A-Z])\$(\d+)(?::\$([A-Z]+)\$(\d+))?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5gVSC/1)